# Removing unwanted brackets from nsarray when data is retrieved from plist

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I am developing a Cocos2d game dynamically by retrieving all the values from plist.For example i am retrieving a value from the plist given in this link:

[image]

That is i want to get the type of animation CCRotateTo and it's values from the plist. Where i did but the value come's with some added brackets like this:

[image]

I have added all the animations such as CCRotateTo , CCScale in an array named seqarray. As the unwanted brackets is added in  each index value of the array it creates a huge problem for me when adding those seqarray values in a CCSequence. It shows some error in the GDB like this:

[image]

Any one Please help me out to solve this issue

EDIT

//ActionValues given in the code have the path of the animation in the plist such as "Scene01.Child.animations". In the key path i will be sending the path inside the ActionValues such as "Animate1.parameters"

```
[seqarray addobject: [self DictValue1:@"Scene01.Mario.animations" Keypath:@"Animate1.parameters"]];
```

I will be passing the scene path and it's animation path to the method below

```
+(id)DictValue1 :(id)actionvalues Keypath:(NSString *)Key1
{
NSArray * multiarrays1 = [actionvalues valueForKeyPath:Key1];
for(id actions in multiarrays1)   
{    
if([[actions valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"CCRotateTo"])
{
[sequenceArray addObject:[self RotateTo:actions]];
}
}
return sequenceArray
}

+(CCRotateTo *)RotateTo:(id)Fadevalues
{
if([Fadevalues isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    CCLOG(@"Fadevalues %@",Fadevalues);//All values with duration angle and type
    CCLOG(@"Fadevalues %@",[Fadevalues valueForKey:@"parameters"]);// Duration value
    NSArray * sss = [Fadevalues valueForKey:@"parameters"];
    CCRotateTo * Rotate = [CCRotateTo  actionWithDuration:[[Fadevalues valueForKey:@"duration"] intValue] angle:[[sss objectAtIndex:0]intValue]];
    return FadeOut;
}
return nil;
```

}

This is the way i am adding the value to the array.  Please help me out to solve this issue

Comment: show us the save/load code.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have edited my question please make a look at it and help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are not your problem.

Let's start from the back: The NSMutableArray is telling you that it received a message `duration` for which there is no corresponding selector. This looks like a logic bug, you probably wanted to send the message to an object stored in the array, not the array itself.

The brackets you see, like:

```
<CCRotateTo = … | Tag = 1>
```

They come from logging the object. For example if you do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", rotateAction);
```

It will run the object's `description` method. This usually returns the object as a string in the syntax above, the object's class name, it's pointer plus additional data enclosed in angle brackets.